# Would the effect of time dilation alone cause the same existing known precession advance of the perihelion of say, Mercury?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time-dilation

Or does this advance also require the bending of space to arrive at the same outcome. In other words if there were no bending of space would the effect of time dilation alone cause an equivalent precession advance of Mercury’s orbit as currently observed – if not how would the orbit differ ? 
I am keen to understand what part time dilation plays in the anomalous orbit of the planets. 
A general explanation would be helpful, rather than extended mathematics (unless felt absolutely  necessary please)

Comment: Time dilation alone is not a theory of gravity. For this question to make sense, you would have to say which theory of gravity, other than GR, you are considering.

Comment: @G.Smith I think OP wants to know whether a GR-ish calculation can be approximated with a Newtonian calculation that somehow accommodates time dilation, put in it by hand. Like e.g. the "old quantum theory" is also not a theory, because it isn't even consistent. Nevertheless, it is useful for calculating some properties of the hydrogen atom.

Comment: In fact it is possible to formulate general relativity as a theory of time dilation, but one cannot ignore the fact that constancy of the speed of light in inertial frames means that the space components of the metric must also be considered.

Comment: What I’m trying to get at is this - if we could leave aside GR for a moment and imagine a thought experiment where planets are orbiting a star as described by Newton. Then we introduce time dilation into the system and no other aspects of GR.. Would the planets orbit continue in an unaffected way or would the time dilation affect the planets orbit ?

Answer (score 0):

In the weak field limit only the time dilation component of the metric is considered. This leads to the Newtonian approximation, that is to say no precession of the orbit. The calculation of orbital precession also takes into account the angular component of the metric. In other words, time dilation on its own does not explain precession.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrectly answered. Half of the orbit the body is accelerated while the other half it is decelerated So, the time dilation which makes the orbit of unequal duration of the halves. That is the same as perihelion advance.Time dilation (SR) explains about half the effect. We need GR for the other half. Maybe someone may confirm.